# How to pass multiple parameters to a Cucumber step?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I want to pass 2 strings from a step as shown in the code below:

testfeature.feature

```
Then Enter Text 'fName' <fname>
Then Enter Text 'mName' <mname>
Then Enter Text 'lName' <lname>

Examples:

| fname | mname | lname |
| FnameTest  | FnameTest  | FnameTest  |
```

testfeature.rb

```
Then /^Enter Text (.*) (.*)$/ do |fieldId|value|
  @browser.text_field(:id, fieldId).set(value)
end
```

Here the fname/lname/mname is being taken from Examples and I am passing the page element through the single quoted string.

Since I'm new with Ruby/Cucumber/Watir, I am not able to understand how this should be handled.

Please Note -
Previously I had written a separate regular expression for all 3 steps, however for optimizing I'm trying this approach.

Looking forward for all happy thoughts :)

Comment: Error being thrown is -

Cucumber::ArityMismatchError: Your block takes 1 argument, but the Regexp matched 2 arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ruby block parameters are separated with `,`, not `|`. Ruby will parse what you wrote like

```
Then /^Enter Text (.*) (.*)$/ do |fieldId|
  value | @browser.text_field(:id, fieldId).set(value)
end
```

To fix it, use a comma:

```
Then /^Enter Text (.*) (.*)$/ do |fieldId, value|
  @browser.text_field(:id, fieldId).set(value)
end
```